# Dynamic function

Tags: javascript, function

I have function say **func()** in a js code

Now I need to pass parameters in such a way that when I click a button the on-click should call the function as **func(param1)**
On next button click it should call the function as **func(param1, param2)** and so on

**func(param1, param2, param 3........)**

How to dynamically increase the parameters of this function ? Any basic java implementation logic would be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify java or javascript?

Comment: Java has varargs, Javascript has `Function#apply`. Which one?

Comment: Java Script. Sorry for not specifying

Answer (score 1):

For javascript you can integrate some method that uses [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

If you want to call that function you can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 0):

@jerone is probably giving you the answer to the question you have asked. However I can hardly imagine any situation in which what you have asked for is the best solution to a problem so maybe if you tell us WHY you want to increase the number of arguments we can offer an alternative, more standard approach .